# return file inside an if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, request

I am trying to return only the response of status code that is 200, and its inside an if statement, when I put the return preddata inside the if statement, nothing gets returned, when I put it outside, I get an error that UnboundLocalError: local variable 'preddata' referenced before assignment, how can I solve this,
this is the code:

```
def obtain_data(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # getting data in the json format
        preddata = response.json()
        preddata=(pd.DataFrame(preddata['hourly']))     
        return preddata
```

Comment: what url are you calling here?

Comment: "nothing gets returned" do you mean it returns an empty dataframe or  None? as if the return statement is not there?
I would try putting another return statement outside like ```return("debug")``` and see if this gets returned.

Comment: its called from the previous function, so that url gets fed in into this function, from  if __name__=='__main__':

Comment: @D.Manasreh it returns as if the return statement is not there

Comment: Try putting another return statement outside like ```return("debug")``` and see if this gets returned.

Comment: If your function returns `None` and not the data frame, then the return statement *isn't* being reached.

Answer (score 1):

If you got `None` returned, it probably means that `response.status_code == 200` is `False`.

(Other option would be that DataFrame constructor generates None, but not possible in the context.)

Comment: No, its true, i tested in the jupyter notebook, outside a function without a return, but want to run it inside a script using functions, hence the return

Comment: you should add some logs.
With print (simple) or logging (better). Print at least `response.status_code` outside the if and `response.json()["hourly"]` inside the if.